# Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using TCPDF to generate the pdf file in codeigniter.clicking. On submit button it displays TCPDF ERROR:

> Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Here is my code:

```
$this -> load -> library('Pdf');
$id = $this -> uri -> segment(3);

$data['profile'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberDetails($id);
$data['job'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberJob($id);
$data['reln'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberRelation($id);

$data['religious'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberReligious($id);
$data['nonreligious'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberNonReligious($id);
$data['courses'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberCourseDetails($id);
$data['member_job'] = $this -> Member_model -> get_job($id);

$data['health'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberHealth($id);
$data['habit'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberHabit($id);
$data['service'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberService($id);
$data['talent'] = $this -> Profile_model -> memberTalent($id);

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf -> SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf -> SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf -> SetTitle('TCPDF Example 002');
$pdf -> SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf -> SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf -> setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf -> setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf -> SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf -> SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$pdf -> SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf -> setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {

  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
  $pdf -> setLanguageArray($l);
}

$pdf -> AddPage();
$html = $this -> load -> view('admin/profile/member_pdf', $data, true);
$filename = $id."-member_profile.pdf";
$pdf -> WriteHTML($html);
ob_end_clean();

$pdf -> Output($filename, 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

based on documention:
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/

```
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = ""
// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();
// ---------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```